# TJSON.JsonToObject do not pass through setters

Tags: rest, oop, delphi, pascal, setter

I'm with some problems when converting a Json string into a Object of my own. I'll give some example:

My class:

```
  TClasse = class
  private
    Fid: integer;
    Fnome: string;
    procedure Setid(const Value: integer);
    procedure SetNome(const Value: string);
  published
    property id : integer read Fid write Setid;
    property nome : string read Fnome write SetNome;
  end;

implementation

procedure TClasse.SetNome(const Value: string);
begin
  Fnome := Value;
  Fnome := 'testing: '+Fnome;
end;
```

I use that method:

```
  cl := TJSON.JsonToObject<TClasse>('{ "id" : 12, "nome" : "abc" }');
```

This means that when the method "JsonToObject" is executed, he will instance my class and set the values to then, passing through the setters. The property "nome" it should have the value "testing: abc", but it has only the "abc" part, from the json. Debugging also do not pass through the setters.

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are doing something wrong... using #$%&??? Delphi built in JSON library that is broken from day one... long story short, it uses fields for serialization instead of properties, right now I don't know if it can be tweaked for using setters.

Comment: Reported as https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-26262

Comment: Probably what you need to do is use bespoke POD types when serializing to and from JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new class e.g. TJSON_Respond to help the serialization

```
TJSON_Respond= class
  public
    [JSONName('id')] id: Integer;
    [JSONName('nome')] nome: String;
  end;

cl := TJson.JSONToObject<TJSON_Respond>('{ "id" : 12, "nome" : "abc" }');
```